# Receiving JSON Exception "Unterminated Array" while parsing html data

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I'm trying to access the google books api and retrieve the list of books according to the keyword entered by the user. While trying to parse the Json Data I receive the following error:

The method I am using to parse JSON data:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 11 of [C@425e2fb8

W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)

W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.readArray(JSONTokener.java:440)

W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:103)

W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)

W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)

W/System.err:     at com.example.android.booklisting.BookListingActivity.readIt(BookListingActivity.java:167)

W/System.err:     at com.example.android.booklisting.BookListingActivity.downloadUrl(BookListingActivity.java:145)

W/System.err:     at com.example.android.booklisting.BookListingActivity.access$100(BookListingActivity.java:39)

W/System.err:     at com.example.android.booklisting.BookListingActivity$DownloadWebpageTask.doInBackground(BookListingActivity.java:96)

W/System.err:     at com.example.android.booklisting.BookListingActivity$DownloadWebpageTask.doInBackground(BookListingActivity.java:90)

W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)

W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)

W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)

W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)

W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)

W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

com.example.android.booklisting I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownViewTheme, referenced from method    com.example.android.booklisting.BooksAdapter.access$super
```

**The Method that I am using to Parse the JSON data:**

```
  public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Reader reader = null;
    reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
    char[] buffer = new char[len];
    reader.read(buffer);
    String jdata = buffer.toString();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(jdata);
        JSONArray jarray = (JSONArray) jsonobject.getJSONArray("items");

        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject volumeInfo = jarray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
            String title = volumeInfo.getString("title");
            JSONArray authors = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
            for (int j = 0; j < authors.length(); j++) {
                String author = authors.getString(i);
                books.add(new Book(title,author));
            }

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return new String(buffer);

}
```

Any idea as to where I might be going wrong in parsing ?? This is my first parsing program.

Comment: check my answer and if it not work then put your json response here

Comment: json response format is not proper

Answer (score 1):

I think error is in your for loop of author so changed it by below code,

```
for (int j = 0; j < authors.length(); j++)
{
    String author = authors.getString(j);
    books.add(new Book(title,author));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are indexing Exception in you code. change to String `author = authors.getString(i);` to `String author = authors.getString(j);`

```
  public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Reader reader = null;
    reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
    char[] buffer = new char[len];
    reader.read(buffer);
    String jdata = buffer.toString();

    try { 
        JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(jdata);
        JSONArray jarray = (JSONArray) jsonobject.getJSONArray("items");

        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject volumeInfo = jarray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
            String title = volumeInfo.getString("title");
            JSONArray authors = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
            for (int j = 0; j < authors.length(); j++) {
                String author = authors.getString(j);
                books.add(new Book(title,author));
            } 

        } 
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 


    return new String(buffer);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check jdata with your JSON response may be you didn't write full string in jdata

please try this to get full string from `InputStream`

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
String line;

while ((line = r.readLine()) != null)
{
    total.append(line).append('\n');
}
```